# Prevent Excel table from auto-populating rows

Tags: excel

If you have an Excel table (listobject) in which all the cells of a column contain the same formula, and you add one or more new rows, the formula will be automatically entered in all the new cells of the column. This is one of my favorite feature of Excel tables.

But my current table has more than one formula in the same column(s). And when I create a new row, it's filling it in with one of those formulas. Not only is it choosing what is usually the **wrong** formula, but in most cases I need the row to be blank.

Is there a way to turn off the auto-fill of table rows? (Especially if I can restrict it to particular columns.)

If necessary, I can write some VBA code to clear the row as its created, but I'd like to see other options first.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/812667-turn-off-auto-fill-table-column.html, but it sounds like you don't want a global option and rather something tied to a specific table or even column.

Comment: Can you share the formulas in your column?  If there are conditions that result in different formulas, you may want to consider consolidating your formula to account for those.  For example, if the cell should be blank the cell in x column is blank, otherwise use a formula, you could add this to your formula... =if(a1="","", and carry on with your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first time you enter a formula in a table column the AutoCorrect options button should display. Click the button and select **Stop Automatically Creating Calculated Columns**. This should turn the autofill off for your table.

Comment: I don't see an AutoCorrect options button. Where exactly does it appear?

Comment: Look at the bottom of this [page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-calculated-columns-in-an-excel-table-873fbac6-7110-4300-8f6f-aafa2ea11ce8), There is an image of the button, it appears right next to the cell that a new formula was entered in. It has a lighting bolt on it. You might have to generate a new calculated column for it to show up.

Comment: I found the option *Fill formulas in tables to create calculated columns* and unchecked it. But the table is STILL filling in the formulas.